# Only validate if called from a specific controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a validation in a model that only is enforced if the model is called from a specific controller.

In my controller I have:

```
@created_by_user = true
@message.save
```

In my model I have

```
validates :subject, length: {in: 0..78, if: @created_by_user}
```

However it seems that even if I save this model from a different script or controller the validation is still checked. How do I get the results I want?

Comment: Specific `controller` or specific `action`?

Comment: When you say action is that a function in a controller? That will work too. If you're saying action like "save" or "create" then that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I mean the `function` or simply call it as `method`.

Comment: If the message.save action is called from the create function inside my message controller then I'd like to do the validation. If it's called from a different script which is ran by a resque job then I don't want the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the controller where you dont need validation, just call

```
@message.save(:validate => false)
```

Comment: I guess this will work but I don't like it at all because it doesn't validate the other validations I have for this model. I wish I could do `@message.save(:validate(:subject, length:) => false)` or something to be more precise.